# Display dropdownlist items depend on another dropdownlist item using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a dropdownlist(name "sub_category) items depend on another dropdownlist(problem_type) item.

**Problem Type** : Select one among the Problem Type: Line Issue, Service Issue,
                       Equipment Issue and Billing Issue.

**Sub category** :

Line Issue – Noisy Line, Call Interference, Line damage.

Service Issue – Major service outage at Provider.

Equipment Issue – Noisy, No Dial Tone, Damaged Equipment.

Billing Issue – Billing paid not updated, Wrong Billing.

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function addList(){
            int i;
            var sub = document.forms["raiseNewFault2"]["sub_category"];
            var main = document.forms["raiseNewFault2"]["problem_type"].value;
            var str1 = new Array("Noisy Line", "Call Interference", "Line damage");
            var str2 = new Array("Major service outage at Provider");
            var str3 = new Array("Noisy", "No Dial Tone", "Damaged Equipment");
            var str4 = new Array("Billing paid not updated", "Wrong Billing");
            if(main.equals("Line issue")){
                for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = option.value = str1[i];
                }
            }
            else if(main.equals("Service issue")){
                for(i=0;i<=0;i++){
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = option.value = str2[i];
                }
            }
            else if(main.equals("Equipment issue")){
                for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = option.value = str3[i];
                }
            }
            else if(main.equals("Billing issue")){
                for(i=0;i<=1;i++){
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = option.value = str4[i];
                }
            }
            select.add(option);
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #raiseNewFault2Div
        {
            margin-top : 25px;
            margin-left : 325px;
            height : 500px;
            width : 600px;
            background-color : #FFDA91;
            border : ridge;
            border-width : "3px"
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="addList()">
    <div id="raiseNewFault2Div">
        <center>
            <form name="raiseNewFault2" action="Controller" method="post">

                <br/><br/>
                <font size="3" color="#006E25">Problem type &nbsp;&nbsp; :   
                 &nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                <select name="problem_type">
                    <option value="Line issue" selected>Line issue</option>
                    <option value="Service issue">Service issue</option>
                    <option value="Equipment issue">Equipment issue</option>
                    <option value="Billing issue">Billing issue</option>
                </select>
               <br/><br/><font size="3" color="#006E25">Sub Category &nbsp;&nbsp; :   
                &nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
                <select name="sub_category"></select>
                </from></center> </div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to check what the user has selected in the first list and then replace the whole second list accordingly with javascript by using:-
`document.getElementById("put the id of the div which contains the list here").innerHTML="put the list you want to replace with the old one here";`

Answer (score 0):

I could simply answer with code, but this site is not meant for it.

You might want to check this : [Populate one dropdown list based on the selection of other dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039740/populate-one-dropdown-list-based-on-the-selection-of-other-dropdown-list)

Hope that helps.